# Open, closed, or neither

Tags: general-topology

Let $B = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R} | x > 0 \land y \neq 0 \}$

I believe that $int(B) = B$, since we can always find a small enough radius for the open ball to be contained in this set; the boundary of $B$ is the set $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R} | x \ge 0 \land y = 0 \}$. Thus $B$ is open, and not closed. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct when you state that $\mathring{B}=B$, but wrong about the boundary of $B$, which happens to be $\left\{(0,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\,y\in\mathbb{R}\right\}\cup\left\{(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\,x\in[0,+\infty)\right\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

Note $B$ is the union of open sets: one is $\pi_Y^{-1}(0)^c$ and the other is $\pi_X^{-1}(0,\infty)$.

**Edit.** You are correct about $B$ being open and not closed, but note the boundary is just the union of the $y$ axis with the right half of the $x$ axis.